# Wait for Datastore callback in Google Cloud Functions (Node-JS)

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-dataflow

I'm developing a Google Cloud Functions that invokes a Dataflow job and storing in the Datastore the ID of the dataflow job. This part works perfect.

My problem is on another Cloud Function (triggered via HTTP) that reads the Datastore. It seems that the Cloud Function is totally asyncronous and ends before the datastore function sends some data.

I took the datastore example from the original node-js datastore api https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-datastore/blob/master/samples/tasks.js

My Code:

```
exports.processJobs = (req, res) => {
jobList = "";
console.log(`  INIT processJobs`);
const query = datastore.createQuery('Job').filter('finished', '=', false);
datastore
.runQuery(query)
.then(results => {
    const jobs = results[0];

    console.log('Jobs:');
    jobs.forEach(job => {
        const jobKey = job[datastore.KEY];
        console.log(jobKey, job);
        jobList = jobList + job.jobId;
    });
})
.catch(err => {
    console.error('ERROR:', err);
});
console.log(`  END processJobs`);
res.status(200).send(":" + jobList);
}
```

If I follow the log generated by my function I shows that the function ends, and after that it shows the jobs into the console:

```
2018-06-25 13:58:00.496  Function execution took 384 ms, finished with status code: 200
2018-06-25 13:59:14.774  Jobs:
2018-06-25 13:59:16.191  undefined { jobId: '2018-06-25_01_07_33-9128665201904101921',
                                                         beginTime: 2018-06-25T08:07:34.980Z,
                                                         finished: false,
                                                         status: 'JOB_STATE_RUNNING' }
```

**UPDATE:**

The solution is moving the response to the "then" part as requested in the solution:

```
datastore
.runQuery(query)
.then(results => {
    const jobs = results[0];
    console.log('Jobs:');
    jobs.forEach(job => {
        const jobKey = job[datastore.KEY];
        console.log(jobKey.id, job);
        jobList = jobList + job.jobId;

    });
    res.status(200).send("Response:_" + jobList );
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you're sending a response before the results are received.  After `res.status().send()` executes, Cloud Functions will clamp down resources on your function and clean it up, possibly killing off any asynchronous work still in progress.

You need to wait until all async work is done before sending a response.  That means you should probably move the response into the `then` and `catch` blocks of your datastore promise so the response is only sent after the work completes.

[See the documentation for more information](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing/http) and examples.